# (Tkinter) Fill the gap between two background images, label border

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a GUI for a Calendar. The blue background image has a grey border where the next image follows it.
I set the background image as Labels. So it seems like a label border.
The top and the Bottom of the image has a grey border. I suppose the grey border isn't on the sides because the image’s full width isn't accommodated to the application.

A picture here,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/73niQ.jpg

**How do I get rid of the grey border where the two images connect?**

Here’s the code,

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import calendar
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

screen = tk.Tk()
screen.geometry("1430x817")
title = screen.title("Class Calendar")
# Icon
img = tk.Image('photo', file = 'Calender_logo.png')
screen.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', screen._w, img)

# Scoll Bar
# main frame that holds everything.
main_frame = Frame(screen, bg = 'blue')
main_frame.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

# canvas that's getting scrolled
Canvasheight, Canvaswidth = 801, 1409.38
canvas = Canvas(main_frame, height = Canvasheight, width = Canvaswidth, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness =0, relief = 'flat', highlightcolor="white", highlightbackground="white")
canvas.pack(side = LEFT, fill= BOTH, expand = 1)

# Add a scrollbar to canvas
scroll_bar = ttk.Scrollbar( main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command = canvas.yview)
scroll_bar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill= Y)

# Bind to mouse scrolling, configuring
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

# Another frame inside the canvas # To hold the things on the canvas
second_frame = Frame(main_frame, height = Canvasheight*8, width = Canvaswidth, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness =0, relief= 'flat', highlightcolor="white", highlightbackground="white") 

# Add new frame to a window in the canvas
canvas.create_window((0,0), window = second_frame, anchor='nw', width= Canvaswidth) # 'w' near middle lower half in scroll bar
second_frame.pack_propagate(False)

####################################### THE BACKGROUND IMAGES
img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Screenshot 2022-06-28 at 10.29.24 AM.png"))
label1 = Label(second_frame, image = img1, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness =0, relief= 'flat', highlightcolor="white", highlightbackground="white")
label1.pack()

img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Screenshot 2022-06-28 at 10.29.24 AM.png"))
label2 = Label(second_frame, image = img2, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness =0, relief= 'flat', highlightcolor="white", highlightbackground="white")
label2.pack()

# MARCH
# PRINTING MARCH TO WINDOW
march22_label = Label(second_frame, text = "MARCH", font = ("arial", 27),fg='black', borderwidth=0, highlightthickness =0)
march22_label.config(bg = '#9ad0f0')
march22_label.place( x= 660, y = 18)


# PRINTING WEEK TO WINDOW
marchweek22_label = Label(second_frame, text = 
"""
  Monday           Tuesday           Wednesday           Thursday             Friday              Saturday              Sunday  
""",                  
font= ('arial', 26),fg='black', borderwidth=0, highlightthickness =0)
marchweek22_label.config(bg = '#a1d0ea')
marchweek22_label.place(x= 100, y = 82)

def March22():
    i = 1
    x, y = 310, 194
    while i < 7:
        Button(second_frame, text = i, font = ("arial", 25), borderwidth=0, highlightthickness =0).place(x = x, y = y)
        x = x + 185
        i = i + 1
    x, y = 125, y + 130
    while i < 14:
        Button(second_frame, text = i, font = ("arial", 25), borderwidth=0, highlightthickness =0).place(x = x, y = y)
        x = x + 185
        i = i + 1
    x, y = 125, y + 130
    while i < 21:
        Button(second_frame, text = i, font = ("arial", 25),borderwidth=0, highlightthickness =0).place(x = x, y = y)
        x = x + 185
        i = i + 1
    x, y = 125, y + 130
    while i < 28:
        Button(second_frame, text = i, font = ("arial", 25),borderwidth=0, highlightthickness =0).place(x = x, y = y)
        x = x + 185
        i = i + 1
    x, y = 125, y + 130
    while i < 32:
        Button(second_frame, text = i, font = ("arial", 25),borderwidth=0, highlightthickness =0).place(x = x, y = y)
        x = x + 185
        i = i + 1
March22()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried using some of the options to `pack`? Maybe on your platform the padding values don't default to zero.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I'm quite new to tkinter. Can you suggest any options I can use or that will be helpful?

Comment: I don't have the gray border when I run your code with my image.

Comment: it's because the image is long enough for the code, I haven't included the other months cause the code will be a little too longer then.